# Lightning record display

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am unable to display data in my component from the controller. It is very simple, but there is some small mistake which I am unable to find out.

```
<aura:component controller="dispacc">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acclst" type="list"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.acclst}" var="ac">

        <div aura:id="{ac.id}">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        kingsize
                        {!ac.id}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <strong>{!ac.name}Hiiiiiii</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!ac.phone}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

#### JavaScript controller

```
({
    myAction : function(component) {
        //alert('getZen');
        var action = component.get("c.find");
        alert('line 5');
        var self = this;
        // alert('after 7');
        action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
            //alert('getZen1');
            var state = actionResult.getState();
            var data=actionResult.getReturnValue();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert('success');
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                component.set("v.acclst", actionResult.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
});
```

#### Apex Controller

```
public class dispacc {
@AuraEnabled
    public  static List<Account> find(){
        return [select id,name,phone from Account limit 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@AuraEnabled` go before the `public class dispacc` line?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - No the methods are auraEnabled not the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eric suggested you need to make changes to correct data type

```
<aura:attribute name="acclst" type="Account[]"/>
```

Plus, Lightning is case sensitive. Can you please change `{!ac.name}` to `{!ac.Name}` and `{!ac.phone}` to `{!ac.Phone}`.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Arpit--Yes i got to know that lightining is case sensitive. That resolved the issue,actually. Even though its working fine with type="list". Thanks for ur help.

Comment: @vineet:- You are welcome. Please mark it as answer so that it can help others as well. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 6):

Your attribute is not of the correct type. Change it to this:

```
<aura:attribute name="acclst" type="Account[]"/>
```

As pointed out in the comment below, `List` with a capital L is a valid type so you may be ok with just capitalizing the L. I would suggest though that you make it `Account[]` to ensure that the type when set is always as expected

Comment: It would work even it's "type=List". The issue here is the case sensitive which is being addressed in the below answer.

Comment: Only if you wanted to enforce a specific type then you can use the appropriate type else "type=List" is fine.

Comment: @Praveen - While `List` is a valid type I am not sure how easy it would be to access to members by dot notation. I have not tried it but not sure if `ac.Name` would resolve if the type is a simple List (Although it might, I have just not tried it). If I expect the result to be a `Account[]` then thats what I would set the type to and consider that the best practice....

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it would work if the field API names are properly referred using dot notation. Also I totally agree with you on the result type being used as the aura:attribute type.

Comment: @Eric - yes you are right,the issue got resolve by keeping 'n' capital in name and 'p'  capital in phone. Anyways its working fine with the type="list". Thanks Eric very much. Its the small things which makes the difference.

Comment: @praveen-yes it worked with field API names referred correctly. Thanks for that point.